# Embed/Attach Base64 Encoded XML into PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have XML in a base64Encoded string. My requirement is to attach base64Encoded xml into pdf. I am using the following example, which  is getting XML from a file, but I need to first decode base64Encoded xml then attach it with a pdf

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'PDFA' => true,
    'PDFAauto' => true,
]);

$mpdf->SetAssociatedFiles([[
    'name' => 'phpunit.xml',
    'mime' => 'text/xml',
    'description' => 'some description',
    'AFRelationship' => 'Alternative',
    'path' => base_path() . '/phpunit.xml'
]]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world 1!</h1>');

return $mpdf->Output();
```

The above example works fine if we pass XML file path, but I have XML in base64 encoded string. How can we attach base64Encoded xml into pdf using `Mpdf` library in `Laravel/PHP`?

Answer (score 0):

To attach data contained in a string, you need to use the `content` entry:

```
$mpdf->SetAssociatedFiles([[
    'name' => 'phpunit.xml',
    'mime' => 'text/xml',
    'description' => 'some description',
    'AFRelationship' => 'Alternative',
    'content' => 'your file content'
]]);
```